# PHP: why !!"0.00" results in true

Tags: php

I have a variable `$amount`, which sometimes can be `"0.00"`. Currently to check if this variable has value and if it's not zero following condition is being used:

```
if (!!$amount)
```

When `$amount` is `"0.00"` or `"0,00"` the condition is `true`, while it should be `false`.

What is the most elegant way to make it `false`? I thought about using

```
if ($amount === "0.0" || $amount === "0,00")
```

and

```
if (!!floatval($amount))
```

but isn't there a better way?

UPDATE: checked again and found out that `.` is a decimal separator, so it can't be "0,00".

Comment: I think if(!!floatval($amount)) is best solution, becouse of $amount can contain a string.

Comment: `floatval("0,5")` will be evaluated as `0`. You can replace `","` by `"."`, but the parsing may give incorrect results for number formated such as : `"42,000.42"`

Comment: How is it possible that you get a value `"0,00"` for the variable `$amount`? I think you need to start by checking the semantics of the logic that generates the value for variable `$amount`..

Comment: @RomeoSierra see update please.

Comment: That practically eases a lot of burden from you. All you need is `if (!!floatval($amount))` now. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`!!"0.0"` and `!!"0,0"` are evaluated as `true` because they are treated as regular non-empty strings and therefore not considered as a falsy value. The only *zero* value in string evaluated as false is `"0"`

You can use regular expressions to check if the input contains only the characters `0`, `.` and `,` :

```
// returns false if $input contains a zero value
function CheckZeroes($input)
{
    return !preg_match('/^[0.,]*$/', $input);
}

$inputs = [ 'a', '0.5', '0,5', '1,000', '1,000.42', '0', '0,0', '0.0', '' ];

foreach ($inputs as $input)
{
    echo "'$input' returns " . (CheckZeroes($input) ? 'true' : 'false') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This outputs :

```
'a' returns true
'0.5' returns true
'0,5' returns true
'1,000' returns true
'1,000.42' returns true
'0' returns false
'0,0' returns false
'0.0' returns false
'' returns false
```

Comment: Your mental effort on coming up with that one-liner solution deserves multiple upvotes..